# pluginutility in Liberty 16.0.0.3 class not found

Tags: websphere-liberty

As I know for Liberty 16.0.0.3 has a new pluginutility function, however when I run it, it always throw NoClassDefFoundError, no matter I'm using oracle / IBM JDK, anyone has this problem too?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ws.http.plugin.merge.PluginMergeToolFactory
```

Comment: Same for me when I invoke the merge using 16.0.0.3 from wasdev and doing no other customization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the pluginUtility and the following APAR will correct this issue : PI69803. Currently the pluginUtility merge action will only work with an ND install.